# How to add members to Telegram with pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I have been able to login to Telegram and send messages to myself and also retrieve users from a group. But whenever I try to add members to a group,  I get an error.

Here is my code

```
from pyrogram import Client
import asyncio
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait

TARGET = 'intendingcouples_class'

async def main():
    app = Client("my_account")

users = []

async with app:
    async for member in app.get_chat_members(TARGET):
        users.append(member.user.id)
    print(users)
    await app.add_chat_members('myenki', member.user.id)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run the above code, I get this error

```
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.flood_420.FloodWait: Telegram says: [420 FLOOD_WAIT_X] - A wait of 73958 seconds is required (caused by "channels.InviteToChannel")
```

Please, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is clear:
`pyrogram.errors.exceptions.flood_420.FloodWait: Telegram says: [420 FLOOD_WAIT_X] - A wait of 73958 seconds is required (caused by "channels.InviteToChannel")`

You'll have to wait `73958` seconds to be able to use the method again. Besides that, adding members against their will to random groups can get both your group, and your account permanently banned.